# HTTP Post with redirect

Tags: redirect, http

So, I've got a HTTP Post that I am doing with two parameters.  I'm not receiving any sort of session ID back to help me with the URL redirect.  Apparently it is more of a 'post to this' and you're in.  Which, I went into Postman and was able to put in the parameters and get a Status 200 OK.  However, the response was HTML.

When I hit Preview in Postman it showed me the webpage that I was needing to be redirected to, essentially.  How can I do a post to redirect like this within Salesforce?  Is that possible or do I have to receive a session ID/cookie back to get something like this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the website that you are posting to and the website it redirects to do not require any authentication then you can use the Apex [HTTP Classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm) in a fairly straightforward way. (You will have to add the site to the [Remote Site Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=configuring_remoteproxy.htm&language=en) too.)

Note though that while sometimes a redirect is done via a 302 status response and a location header, other techniques can be used including JavaScript embedded in a response page. While that is easy for a browser to handle, it is harder to handle in Apex code.

Comment: So the return res.getBody(); is what will redirect me to the success HTML body they send back?

Comment: @DavidLitton The body may just be the success HTML (so you are done) or you could get a 302 response with a location header or you could get JavaScript in the response that does a redirect; you'll have to check the responses. I only mentioned redirect because you did in the question...

Comment: I'm getting an HTML response in the body.  I assume I want to display that on my page when I receive it?

Comment: @DavidLitton Yeah you can output that content if you want to, though see the warning about `escape=false` in [apex:outputText](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm).

Comment: @KeithC have a similar problem and am getting a 302. What should I do?

Comment: @TylerZika See e.g. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136811/httpcallout-error-statuscode-302/136812#136812.