# Tooling API response, how to print in log?

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, tooling-api, httprequest

I’m trying to print (system.debug) the response returned from tooling API but the debug is not displaying anything. So, I was wondering if the code below is correct.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

req.setEndpoint('https://brave-raccoon-5j3npj-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/services/data/v47.0/tooling/sobjects/');
req.setMethod('GET'); 


Http h = new Http();
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
system.debug(res.getBody());
```

Comment: Based on the answers you've gotten so far (and my own attempt to reproduce the issue), it would have been helpful to include the debug log (or a relevant portion of it) in your question. If I didn't already know that you're likely getting a 302 response, I would have probably asked you how you were executing this code (anonymous apex?) and for anything resembling an error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advise and the support.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your code.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

req.setEndpoint('https://brave-raccoon-5j3npj-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/services/data/v47.0/tooling/sobjects/');
req.setMethod('GET'); 

Http h = new Http();
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
while (res.getStatusCode() == 302) {
    req.setEndpoint(res.getHeader('Location'));
    res = new Http().send(req);
    system.debug(res.getBody());
}
```

This stackexchange post has answer to why you need to handle '302' above.
[[HttpCallout error [StatusCode=302]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136811/httpcallout-error-statuscode-302])

Hope this helps.

Comment: An important note is that the reason why OP got a blank debug in their log is because the body of the response is itself empty when Salesforce gives us this 302 response (and I got a 302 myself when I tried to reproduce OP's issue).

Comment: Thanks a lot this was very helpful. This solved the redirection problem but for some reason the debug is still not showing up the objects.

Comment: Seems like you are using a scratch org. Could you please paste the debug response. Are you seeing any errors with response?